# Where is my application binary in Xcode to submit?

Tags: ios, xcode, binary, app-store-connect

I've built an app for the App Store (ex-iTunes store).  However, I can't figure out how to submit the app.

Where is the actual binary that I need to submit to the App Store?  What folder does it get built in?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You could use XCode and on the left expand "Products".  Highlight your .app and then go up top where it says "Action" drop that down and select "Reveal in Finder"

Comment: This answer is XCode version independent and the project file structure is significantly changed from 3.x to 4.x.  Keep in mind that the "Derived Data" folder is hidden in some of the Finder views (i.e., during attachment in email).

Comment: What about if the application file is grayed out?  What does that mean?

Comment: When I right click the myapp.app under Products, the Show in Finder option is disabled in the context menu. I am using XCode Version 4.5.1. Any other way?

Comment: THIS SHOULD BE THE ACCEPTED ANSWER!
I'm in xcode 9.4 (using macincloud)
@Farish First highlight myapp.app. Then right click.

Answer (score 24):

Look at a path something like this:

"/Users/{user}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{appname-somehash}/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/{app-name}.app"

You can run "find" to locate it.

Comment: This is correct for default configurations only. My products are saved relatively to the projects location.

Comment: how do you "products are saved relatively to the projects location" ?

Answer (score 3):

By default, you'll see a build directory inside the directory containing your project.
In that build directory:

`<Project Name>`.build` contains all the object files created during compilation

and a series of folders with the following naming scheme:

```
<build setting>-<platform>
```

You're likely looking for something like "Release-iphoneos".  In that folder you should find the .app package to submit.

Comment: Is it the same in XCode 4? I can't find it (using XCode 4 preview 2).

Comment: @TomA - no.  See the answer below that recommends revealing the product file in finder.  That is a more foolproof answer across releases of the IDE.

Comment: @mobibob yup, since posting that comment I have found the Derived Data folder and bookmarked it in Finder.