# Facebook iOS crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I am trying to set up facebook SDK 3.5 for iOS. I have gotten it to work just fine but it is now crashing. The crash only seems to happen when a user is logged in through the default iOS facebook settings (AKA not the facebook application from the app store). The app crashes specifically when the facebook "login" view is tapped.

The crash is: error: [NSError fberrorShouldNotifyUser]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I have done some [Research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640510/facebook-ios-sdk-3-2-1-nserror-fberrorshouldnotifyuser-unrecognized-selecto) and some people are suggesting to put -Objc to "other linker flags". I don't have that exactly but I have something similar I think. I needed the other options for other libraries. Here are my options:

[image]

Can anyone tell me if this is causing the problem? If not, does anyone know what really is causing the crash? Thanks!

**EDIT**

It would seem that the error is happening in this method on the very first "if"

```
- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView
  handleError:(NSError *)error {
NSString *alertMessage, *alertTitle;
if (error.fberrorShouldNotifyUser) // CRASH HERE {
// If the SDK has a message for the user, surface it. This conveniently
// handles cases like password change or iOS6 app slider state.
alertTitle = @"Facebook Error";
alertMessage = error.fberrorUserMessage;
} else if (error.fberrorCategory == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession) {
 // It is important to handle session closures since they can happen
// outside of the app. You can inspect the error for more context
// but this sample generically notifies the user.
alertTitle = @"Session Error";
alertMessage = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";
 } else {
 // For simplicity, this sample treats other errors blindly.
alertTitle  = @"Unknown Error";
alertMessage = @"Error. Please try again later.";
NSLog(@"Unexpected error:%@", error);
}
}
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15640510/1402846

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. According to this

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/#prerequisites

you need to set the `-ObjC` flag or use `FBErrorUtility` instead of `fberror*`

I just added the -ObjC flag and it worked fine.

Comment: The `-ObjC` flag can unnecessarily bloat your final binary by including all Objective-C object files in all referenced libraries whether they are used in your application or not. It should be treated as a last resort, not a magical flag that just makes things work. Instead, consider the `-force_load` linker flag to explicitly include individual libraries that are not being linked properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using a project using ARC, you don't need to add this linker flag.

Make sure that, in your code, the `NSError+FBError.h` file is imported, that's where it's pulling that category from.

Technically, if you're importing `<FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>`, that category definition is included.

Also, if your code can't find that header file, make sure that the `FacebookSDK.Framework` is included in the list of linked frameworks and library in your target's summary page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Some projects are using ARC, some aren't hence why I have that. Is that fine then? Mine isn't using ARC though. I am importing <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h> and when I click show in finder it takes me to the FacebookSDK folder so I believe that is fine. The only file I cannot find is the NSError+FbError.h file.. Not sure if you intended them to be separate but can't find them separately either. Any other suggestions? Thank you

Comment: The file should be in ~/Documents/FacebookSDK/Headers. In Xcode, if you expand the FacebookSDK.framework, are the files listed in red? Did you copy the framework files when you dragged them to your project?

Comment: I cannot remember if I simply dragged or how I had imported it. I apologize. But when I expand the FacebookSDK.framework I see a blue "Header" folder and none of the files are red which I assume means they are added correctly.

Comment: And also everything runs fine if the user isn't logged in through the integrated iOS feature so I assume the facebook sdk is fine?

Comment: It sounds like it's imported correctly. The class that handles the login view includes the FacebookSDK.h file?

Comment: I have the following line declared in the view that handles the login. #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>  The view is the Facebook blue button that is the FBLoginView class

Comment: It seems I have found where the exact crash is. Please see my updated answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When the device comes back to your app from the Facebook login your app must be running in the background. I fixed this error by turning on "fast app switching". Its the setting under the targets Info tab called "Application does not run in background". It should be NO.